# Proof of Stiemke's Theorem via Dubovitskii–Milyutin

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, linear-programming

Prove that the system
$$\sum_{i=1}^{m} x_i a_i = 0, x_i > 0, i = 1, . . . , m,$$

has no solution if and only if the system
$$<a_i , y> ≤ 0, i = 1, . . . , m,$$ 
not all zero has a solution.
Hint: Use the finite-dimensional version of the Dubovitskii–Milyutin theorem.

## Proof

Let $K_i=\{x:x_i >0\}, i=1,...,m$, $K_{m+1}=Ker(A)$ where $A=[a_1,...,a_m]$.

Comment: I know I want to compute $K_{i}^{*}$ and then use the Dubovitskii–Milyutin theorem. But i dont know how to